# Removing elements not found in two arrays in php

Tags: php

Say you have the following two array:

> ```
>      array1 = dogs, cat, rat, pig
>      array2 = dogs, cat, pig
> ```

I want to compare these two arrays and remove elements that are not found in these two arrays to create a new array.

So the above two arrays would become:

```
tags = dogs, cat, pig
```

Is there a function in php for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [array_intersect](http://php.net/array_intersect)

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

The `$result` would be:

```
Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/array_intersect) (click to see documentation).

BTW: This was the first search result for `PHP array intersect`...